# How to set the height of a window using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Is it possible to set the height of a window using the window handle or process handle?

I have the following so far, assume the application in question is notepad.

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");

foreach (Process p in processes)
{

    if (p.MainWindowTitle == title)
    {

        handle = p.MainWindowHandle;

        while ((handle = p.MainWindowHandle) == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            p.Refresh();
        }

        break;
    }

}
```

Can I make use of `handle` or `p` to set the height of the window?

Comment: Using the window handle, pinvoke GetWindowRect to get rect, modify the height and then pinvoke MoveWindow.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct RECT
        {
            public int left;
            public int top;
            public int right;
            public int bottom;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref RECT Rect);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int Width, int Height, bool Repaint);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
            foreach (Process p in processes)
            {
                IntPtr handle = p.MainWindowHandle;
                RECT Rect = new RECT();
                if (GetWindowRect(handle, ref Rect))
                    MoveWindow(handle, Rect.left, Rect.right, Rect.right-Rect.left, Rect.bottom-Rect.top + 50, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While you can do it with `SetWindowPos`, and `SetWindowPos` is the newer and more capable API, `MoveWindow` is just easier to call.

Comment: Excellent! Works in Silverlight OOB (and probably elevated in-browser as well). Of course it will require FindWindow to get handle.

Comment: I think the Rect struct is wrong. It should be Left, Top, Right, Bottom

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to use the Win32 [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545.aspx) function (use for both position and size). Here's a [link](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setwindowpos) for how to do it in C#.

Here's a quick sample. This will move notepad to (10,10) on the screen, and resize it to (450,450):

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, SetWindowPosFlags uFlags);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start notepad and hit any key...");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");

        foreach (Process p in processes)
        {
            var handle = p.MainWindowHandle;

            SetWindowPos(handle, new IntPtr(SpecialWindowHandles.HWND_TOP), 10,10,450,450,SetWindowPosFlags.SWP_SHOWWINDOW);

            break;

        }

    }
}

public enum SpecialWindowHandles
{
    HWND_TOP = 0,
    HWND_BOTTOM = 1,
    HWND_TOPMOST = -1,
    HWND_NOTOPMOST = -2
}

[Flags]
public enum SetWindowPosFlags : uint
{
    SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS = 0x4000,

    SWP_DEFERERASE = 0x2000,

    SWP_DRAWFRAME = 0x0020,

    SWP_FRAMECHANGED = 0x0020,

    SWP_HIDEWINDOW = 0x0080,

    SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x0010,

    SWP_NOCOPYBITS = 0x0100,

    SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002,

    SWP_NOOWNERZORDER = 0x0200,

    SWP_NOREDRAW = 0x0008,

    SWP_NOREPOSITION = 0x0200,

    SWP_NOSENDCHANGING = 0x0400,

    SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001,

    SWP_NOZORDER = 0x0004,

    SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040,
}
```

Comment: That is awesome! I'd like to leave the width of the window as the original width how can I do this?

Comment: Call GetWindowRect. MoveWindow is easier to use than SetWindowPos.

Comment: @David - I am not familiar with that, maybe you can add an example?

Comment: @Abs: Use the GetWindowRect function to get the size as David suggested, and use the width from that. See here: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/getwindowrect.html

Comment: You have forget explicit SpecialWindowHandles
 to int