# Get a running process' dimensions

Tags: c#, .net, process

I'm trying to grab a screen shot of a specific x, y location in an application. Is there any way to get a running app in a Process object, then get the dimensions of it?

Something like:

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (Process proc in processlist)
{
Console.WriteLine("Process: {0} ID: {1}", proc.Width, proc.Height);
}
```

Comment: What would you expect to happen if the process in question had multiple windows open?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are probably other ways to do this but here's a quick high level solution:

1. get the main window handle ([Process.MainWindowHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowhandle.aspx)).
2. Get the window height using the win32 API function [GetWindowRect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6485074/52136) to a SO question shows getting the window size and then setting it.

Edit:
I realize this answer assumes that the process only has a single window.  This SO [question/answer(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79111/net-c-getting-child-windows-when-you-only-have-a-process-handle-or-pid) describes getting all of the windows for a process.