# Control the size of the browser window when i open a link using Process.Start()?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, process.start

I cannot use Web Browser control to display html content because i'm using Background worker to open the form.

And therefor i'm using Process.Start() to open a link that contain only a facebook like button

```
Process.Start("http://www.example.com");
```

Is there any possibility to control the size of opened window (Height, Width) and start position?

Comment: This may be relevant -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484567/how-to-set-the-height-of-a-window-using-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cannot use Web Browser control to display html content because i'm
>   using Background worker to open the form.

In this case you could perform this inside an [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) delegate. Or since you are using a `BackgroundWorker` use the [RunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx) event which is executed once the background task completes.

Comment: @Daniel, why do you think so? It answers the OP's question who is asking how to display the results of some background operation in a web browser and have the possibility to control the width, height and start position of this browser window. Or am I wrong?

Comment: RunWorkerCompleted saved my day! Thankyou @Darin Dimatrov